# Associative array triggered from Custom Taxonomy (WordPress PODS)

Tags: pods-framework

I have national flag icons that I (manually add) on some posts when that nation is referenced.

Here is the code for that:

```
<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-us"></span>
```

All nice and simple. As you can see from the code, the bit flag-icon-us will pull the US Flag which is actually an SVG image file.

My question is - is there any way you can think of so that when I select the Custom (Pods) Taxonomy of “United States” that someone adds that line of code?

Perhaps some sort of associative array or other?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to have the flag span added automatically your post when it is associated with the country custom taxonomy, right? If that is the case, then you could add the following helper functions to your `functions.php` and then use them in your post template.

The example assumes that the term slug matches the flags css class suffix (eg. United States -> us).

```
// functions.php
function get_post_locale(int $id)
{
  $terms = get_the_terms( $id, 'your_custom_taxonomy' ); // add correct taxonomy name here
  return ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) ? $terms[0]->slug : '';
}

function print_post_locale_flag(string $locale)
{
  if ( $locale ) {
    printf(
      '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-%s"></span>',
      esc_attr($locale)
    );
  }  
}

// single post template
print_post_locale_flag( get_post_locale( get_the_ID() ) );
```

Of course you can have another helper function to map the term slugs to correct css classes, if you want.